# Let $G$ be a finite group, $S$ a sylow subgroup of $G$ and $H<G$ such that $N_G(S)\subseteq H$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group, $S$ a sylow subgroup of $G$ and $H<G$ such that $N_G(S)\subseteq H$.
>
> (1) Show that for all $x\in N_G(H), xSx^{-1}$ is a sylow subgroup of $H$.
>
> (2) Show that $N_G(H)=H$.

For the first one I did like that... If $x\in N_G(H) \implies xHx^{-1}=H.$ Since $N_G(S)\subseteq H$, in particular $S\subseteq H$ because $S\subseteq N_G(S).$ Hence $xSx^{-1}=S\subseteq H=xHx^{-1}$.

But I don't know if I can say that $S$ is a $p$-sylow subgroup of $H$. And for the second part I know that $H$ is in $N_G(H)$ but don't know how to proceed and prove the other inclusion.

Comment: Where did these problems arise?

Comment: $p$ is relatively prime to $[G:S]=[G:H][H:S]$, so $p$ is relatively prime to $[H:S]$ and $S$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You cannot say that $S_1=xSx^{-1}=S$. But since $x\in H, S\subseteq H$,
   $S_1\le H$. Since $|S_1|=|S|$, $S_1$ is also a Sylow subgroup of $G$, hence of $H$.
2. Clearly $N_G(H)\ge H$. Let $x\in N_G(H)$. Then $xHx^{-1}=H$. Hence $xSx^{-1}\le H$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$. Then by the Sylow theorem there exists an element $h\in H$ such that $hSh^{-1}=xSx^{-1}$ or $(x^{-1}h)S(x^{-1}h)^{-1}=S$. This means $x^{-1}h\in N_G(S)\le H$, so $x\in H$. Hence $N_G(H)=H$.

Answer (score 0):

Saying $S$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup is easy. If $T$ is a $p$-subgroup of $H$ containing $S$, then it's a $p$-subgroup of $G$ containing $S$. Because $S$ is maximal in $G$, $S = T$. Hence, $S$ is also maximal in $H$. A slightly more cumbersome proof, but more instructive I feel, would be to think deeply on how Lagrange's theorem applies to this.